# if statement in for each loop

Tags: foreach

I am trying to write a foreach loop where I print out one item in a list followed by a blank line. The problem is that I want to do this for every iteration after the first iteration, so that I print the first item then a blank line, then the second item, etc, instead of a blank line before the first item.

```
\foreach [count=\i] \x in {#1}{ 
            \hspace{0.646cm}
            
            \x
            }
}
```

I suspect I would need to add some kind of if statement, but I do not know how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please give a Minimum Working Example (MWE): [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: Not at pc but would `\ifnum\i>1... \fi` do it?

Comment: @daleif Yes this worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `[count=\i]`  you can use

```
\ifnum\i>1\relax code\fi
```